# editing mode UITableView, cant prevent movement of content view to right

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my chat application, i can't prevent movement of some content views to right, on screenshot blue bubble with text movement to right in edit mode, can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following UITableView Delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Credits are from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5789624/2060180