# UITableView's shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath: is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to prevent content of table cells from shifting to the left side when using table editing mode. I implemented the following `UITableViewDelegate` method in my view controller:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

as suggested in:

[Prevent indentation of UITableViewCell (contentView) while editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789467/prevent-indentation-of-uitableviewcell-contentview-while-editing)

But it doesn't seem to be ever called. This didn't work either:

```
cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
```

I'm using a couple of custom edit row actions that are defined like this:

```
- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                  editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *actions = [NSMutableArray array];
    id clearHandler = ^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
            ...
    };
    UITableViewRowAction *clearAction = [UITableViewRowAction
                                         rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDestructive
                                         title:@"Clear\nStatus"
                                         handler:clearHandler];
    [actions addObject:clearAction];

    id editHandler = ^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        ...
    };
    UITableViewRowAction *editAction = [UITableViewRowAction
                                        rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal
                                        title:@"Edit"
                                        handler:editHandler];
    [actions addObject:editAction];

    return actions;
}
```

I double checked that the `delegate` property of the table view is pointing to the view controller. What else am I missing?

Table view style is not grouped, i.e. plain.

Comment: Are you using a grouped table view? From `UITableView.h`: "This method only applies to grouped style table views."

Comment: did you solve your issue or not ?

Comment: @norders Table style is plain. So it's not possible to achieve this for plain table view?

Comment: I don't know, but try switching the table style to 'grouped'. If it works, then I'd say 'no' ;-)

Comment: Try using custom UITableViewCell & set position of items in the cell with xib file.

Answer (score 0):

**Set delegate and datasource method**

then

- You set the `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` property of UITableView to true.