# No Indentation in Custom TableCell while Editing TableView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview

I've spent a lot of time today trying to figure out how to get my custom table cell (built using XIB) to stop indenting when in editing mode.

I have looked all over the place, Examples: [Prevent indentation of UITableViewCell (contentView) while editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789467/prevent-indentation-of-uitableviewcell-contentview-while-editing) and [How can I change the amount of indentation on my custom UITableViewCell while editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713192/how-can-i-change-the-amount-of-indentation-on-my-custom-uitableviewcell-while-edi/5713349#5713349) but seem to be running into the same problem that the OP ran into with the cell jumping around.

Has any one found a better way to solve this problem?

Basically I have a CustomTableCell, and when I enter Editing mode on that cell, I want the cell to stay where it is with no indentation.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. I managed to make the solution posted in the links work using a hack: In layoutSubviews I just did self.indentationWidth = 0.0001; :. Not the cleanest solutions but it works.

Comment: Where is layout subviews? is that of the cell? or the cell background view or what? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath: delegate method to return  No. If that doesn´t work go to the .xib and open the utilities view (the one in the right). From there disable "use Autolayout" in the file inspector tab and disable "indent while editing" in the attributes inspector.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the delegate method `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` and return `false`.

From the docs: "Asks the delegate whether the background of the specified row should be indented while the table view is in editing mode."

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it's not any sort of hack but the proper approach

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that if you put a custom cell's subviews on a UIView that is between approximately 300 and 320 points wide, and then add said subview to the cell's content view, it will not move the subview upon triggering editing mode.

Comment: Interesting. I managed to make the solution posted in the links work using a hack:

In layoutSubviews I just did self.indentationWidth = 0.0001; :\. Not the cleanest solutions but it works.